# How to add icon to list elements

Tags: html, css

How can I add an icon to every list element?

```
        <nav class="mobile">
            <ul>
                <li><img class="icon" src="images/ico/home.png" style="width:10px; height:10px; margin: 2px; float:left;"/><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I've tried this so far, but my icon is not in line with `<a>` element.

Comment: your code works fine in chrome 62. without the class you have there. only the inline style.  icon is in the same line as the <a>

Answer (score 3):

You can use variety of tools like font icons from font awesome or even you own custom font. Just use the pseudo class :before to the li and then add content to it.

```
li:before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```css
li:before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, just use css in header:

```
<style type="text/css">
    li:id1 {
        list-style-image: url('anyimg1.gif');
    }

    li:id2{
        list-style-image: url('anyimg2.gif');
    }
</style>
```

And HTML:

```
<ul>
      <li id="id1"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li id="id2"><a href="index.php">Articles</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will add the same icon for every list item. I need a different icon for each li element.

Comment: if you want that just use "li#someid" in css and then <li id="someid"> and next <li id="someid2"> by creating next li#id element in css